# Build Mega Menu In Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, menu, nodes, umbraco7, megamenu

I'm building a web application using Umbraco V7.4.
I use the Umbraco just to manage content , and I read it through API controller.
For my site i need 'Mega-Menu' that look like the one in this site:
[full menu](http://www.foodnetwork.com/)
My question is: What is the best way to do this in Umbraco? How to build the structure of Document Types? How to send it in API ?

Thank's in advance to all helpers !

Comment: There's no one way to do this - it depends on your current content structure. Also, this is very vague; I assume the question is a three parter:
1) how do I structure my data and content to that I can build a navigation menu?
2) how do I set up a service to emit just the relevant information to build a menu?
3) how do I build a mega menu to consume a service that contains hierarchical links?

Comment: Agree with @cooper, it all depends on your content hierarchy. If you have implemented something already, can you please attach a screenshot of the content tree or otherwise add a description of how you envisage the content structure within Umbraco?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it !!!
Their is dataType named Archetype (u need to download package) the Archetype lets you to build Mega menu and match more !!!
This is the most generic datatype i found !
Here is the link:
[Umbraco Archetype](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/archetype/)